# Width issue on tables with rowspan on Safari and Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari, width, html-table

I have a problem with table cell width on tables with rowspan defined on Safari and Chrome. I don't know if it's a bug or if I'm missing anything.
This is the simple HTML code to reproduce it:

```
<table style="width:1000px" border="1">
<tr>
    <td style="width:50px">a1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">b1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">c1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>a2 and b2 and c2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]
In Firefox I the first column has a width of 50px, but not in Safari and Chrome (much bigger).

Comment: I have just tested this in the latest version of Chrome and it seems to work as expected (once the missing </table> tag is added). Can you confirm it works for you?

Comment: Works in latest versions of Chrome and Safari on Windows for me as well. I assume you still have the end `</table>` tag even though you didn't put it in your code above, yes? Do you have any CSS styles overriding anything? Perhaps post the whole page HTML here--maybe some HTML isn't valid that is breaking this snippet?

Comment: The missing </table> was a visualization error (was not styled as code in stackoverflow, thus missing). I added an image to show what I mean